# Read specific data from Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to load specific child's from the current user but it is displaying the info from all users.

[image: image of Firebase database]
[image: screenshot of emulator]

```
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_user_profile, container, false);

        btEdit = v.findViewById(R.id.button_edit);
        mChildValueTextView = v.findViewById(R.id.childValueTextView);
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final DatabaseReference mRef = database.getReference("Users");

        mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String childValue = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());
                mChildValueTextView.setText(childValue);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) 
    {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following line of code:

```
String childValue = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());
```

It means that you are getting all users within your `Users` node. If you want to get a single user, the authenticated user, you should go a level deeper in the tree. I assume that `fp60 ... Xez1` is the id of the user that comes from the authentication process, to get its data, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String age = dataSnapshot.child("age").getValue(String.class);
        String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
        String sex = dataSnapshot.child("sex").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", name + ", " + sex + ", " + age);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Asuming that the authenticated user has as the uid the above example `fp60 ... Xez1`, the outout in your logcat will be:

```
carlostest2, m, 28
```

Comment: Hello and thank you, I am receiving an error with the TAG from the Log.TAG. Cannot resolve symbol TAG. Do i need to add a specific dependency to the gradle?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Just changed `TAG` with `"TAG"` in both places. Does it wok now?

Comment: The error is gone now. When I run the app, nothing is displayed in the textview, it is empty. Do I need to include the textview in the code?

Comment: Ok so I've added my mChildValueTextView.setText(childValue); and now i'm seeing the data displayed just as you said it would. Thank very much for the help!

Comment: I will post a new question on how to change the font output of the results, I would appreciate if you knew anything about that to check out my next question.

Comment: Ok, post the new question. If I'll know the answer, I'll write it to you.